# Retrieving count of specific attribute in MongoDB collection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with a lot of data.

Part of my JSON documant looks like this:

```
{
  "_id":{
    "$oid":"5364e0867a2690e2a2be13ff"
  },
  "share_name":"test123",
  "data_objects":[
    {
      "user":"The Flying Pirate.",
      "location":"Devon, UK.",
      "share_id":462568869077716992
    },
    {
      "user":"The Dragon.",
      "location":"London, UK.",
      "share_id":462568869077716992
    },
    {
      "user":"lozzien",
      "location":"Miami, USA.",
      "share_id":462568869077716992
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, a single document can have list of data_objects. The above document has 3 data objects. I need to get the total count of data objects in this collection. How can I get this total count?

Answer (score 0):

What you are basically after is "summing up" the total length of the array elements contained in your document for the collection.

With MongoDB 2.6 this is quite simple thanks to the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "totalSize": { "$sum": { "$size": "data_objects" } }
    }}
])
```

In prior versions you are going to need other methods to get the array "size". Notably th [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$data_objects" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "totalSize": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

And since the array content is now "de-normalized" it's just a matter of counting the total entries. So [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) 1 in this case for each expanded document in the collection.

Writing this up for the Java driver is not hard:

```
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject(
        "$group", new BasicDBObject(
            "_id",null
        ).append(
            "totalSize", new BasicDBObject(
                "$sum", new BasicDBObject(
                    "$size", "data_objects"
                )
            )
        )
    );

    db.getCollection("collection").aggregate(Arrays.asList(group));
```

Ideally though you should consider "storing" the array length in the document. This is useful for "query" purposes and negates the need to calculate this "on the fly". Handle additions with the [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator alongside [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/):

For adding data to the array:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": Objectid("5364e0867a2690e2a2be13ff") },
    {
        "$push": { "data_objects": newObject },
        "$inc": { "data_count": 1 }
    }
)
```

And removing:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": Objectid("5364e0867a2690e2a2be13ff") },
    {
        "$pull": { "data_objects": removeReqery },
        "$inc": { "data_count": -1 }
    }
)
```

Then you are performing the same aggregation all of the time:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "totalSize": { "$sum": "$data_count" }
    }}
])
```